# R Parallel EasyABC or smfsb: ABC-SMC

Tags: r

I have a simple ODE with some unknown parameters (r, C, d and g) that predicts the decay and regrowth of bacteria on a surface after being cleaned. I have experimental data for the number of bacteria at various times points (0h, 1h, 2h, 4h, 8h and 24h) after cleaning. I'm trying to use the EasyABC package to estimate the parameter distributions r, C, d and g by an Approximate Bayesian Computation Sequential Monte Carlo Simulation approach.

[image]

## Install necessary packages

```
if("deSolve" %in% rownames(installed.packages())==FALSE){install.packages("deSolve"); require(deSolve)}else{require(deSolve)}
```

## The equation function:

```
ode_model <- function(time_space, initial_contamination, parameters){
  with(
    as.list(c(initial_contamination, parameters)),{
      dContamination <- Contamination*r*(1-Contamination/C)-d*exp(-g*time_space)*Contamination
      return(list(dContamination))
    }
  )
}
```

## Produces Bacteria count at 5 time-points

```
deterministic_run<-function(precision,initial_contamination,parameters){
  tmax = 24
  time_space = seq(0, tmax, length.out = precision+1)

sim<- ode(initial_contamination, time_space, ode_model, parameters, method = "radau",atol = 1e-4, rtol = 1e-4)
num_at_1=sim[(precision*1/50.0),2]
num_at_2=sim[(precision*2/50.0),2]
num_at_4=sim[(precision*4/50.0),2]
num_at_8=sim[(precision*8/50.0),2]
num_at_24=sim[(precision*24/50.0),2]


return(cbind(num_at_1,num_at_2,num_at_4,num_at_8,num_at_24))
}
```

## This runs the ODE solver

```
trial_r = runif(1,1E-1,4)
trial_C = runif(1,6,15)
trial_d = runif(1,1,4)
trial_g = runif(1,1E-2,1)
trial_l = runif(1,1E-5,2)
parameters=c(r=trial_r,C=trial_C,d=trial_d,g=trial_g,l=trial_l)

initial_contamination=59
precision=5000

one_run = deterministic_run(precision,initial_contamination,parameters)#
```

## Plot

```
plot(one_run)
```

I'm trying to use the EasyABC package: http://easyabc.r-forge.r-project.org to estimate the parameters in the ODE and in many ways is an easier example than the ones given in the documentation but I cannot figure out how to feed my function into it. Does anyone have a similar example?

Comment: Let's hope you get an answer, otherwise you may contact the [authors](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=EasyABC) directly, or use an [alternative package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=FME).